# How to change the start up file in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am trying to open a file which is in different folder as start up file. How can I do that? I am working with visual studio windows forms. Let us say I have a folder name 'Forms' and in that I created two forms LoginForm and MainForm. When I run the project I want 'LoginForm' to open which is in Forms Folder.

Thank you

Comment: If you added a Form directly to a sub-folder of your Project, the automatic feature (which issues a waning), has probably added a nested namespace to the Form (corresponding to the name of the Folder - so don't use reserved or *confusing* names for these folders). You can remove it or use the full definition when you create an instance of this Form. e.g. `var form2 = new Forms.Form2();`

Comment: Note that if `LoginForm` is your starting Form, when you close it you also close the application.

Comment: Open the “Program.cs” file in the project. Look for… `Application.Run(new FormX());` … in this case “FormX” is run. Change it to the form you want to start when the project is run.

Answer (score 0):

Each folder in the project will be treated as a namespace, so you can access it through the full namespace.

[image]

And change the start Form in Program.cs.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Forms.LoginForm());
```

Comment: Are you ***sure*** about this behavior?  Please show some sort of reference.  I am NOT saying you are wrong but I have never heard of that and it seems kindof screwed up to have namespaces created just because of my folder organization.

Comment: IThe default behavior when adding items to the project in folders is to use the namespace with the folder. If you create an item in the root and move it to the folder, the namespace won't automatically be changed. but creating it directly in the folder will append the folder to the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, that you want the Login form to show before the Main form shows.
You probably also want to use the result of the login process to decide what to do.

My advice would be to use the [Form.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=netcore-3.1) event. This event will be raised just before the Form is loaded. Use visual studio designer to add this event:

```
void OnFormLoaded(object sender, ...)
{
    // just before showing the main form show the Login form
    using (var logonForm = new MyLogonForm())
    {
        logonForm.SomeProperty = ...
        logonForm.SomeOtherProperty = ...
        DialogResult dlgResult = logonForm.ShowDialog();

        switch (dlgResult)
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                // Operator logged on correctly:
                User loggedOnUser = logonForm.LoggedOnUser;
                ProcessLoggedOnUser(loggedOnUser);
                break;
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                // Operator decided to cancel logon:
                ProcessCancelledLogOn();
                break;

            case DialogResult.Abort:
                // Operator aborted the startup process: close the program
                LogCloseProgram();
                this.Close();
                break;

             default:
               throw new NotImplementedException(); // TODO: implement
        }
    }
}
```